# What is the "stamp" number font on those BB 67200 locomotives?

Tags: font-identification

I've looked pretty much everywhere and I'm only posting here because I'm out of ideas. I'm looking for the font that is used to display the locomotive numbers on some specific SNCF (french rail) BB 67200 (series of locomotives).

I've tried the usual font-ID sites, except photoshop.

Unfortunately, due to the nature of this "series", the first numbers are always "672", and, obviously there is only numbers, making any identification a bit tricky.

[image]

It's displayed on the side of the locomotive:

[image]

Here are some other examples:

[image]

It's even reproduced on this toy train:
[image]

EDIT:

<strike>I've just found more details, it MIGHT be the font used for the 1967 SNCF logo:</strike>

[image]

[image]

But using the logo in the usual font-ID websites doensn't yield good results...

EDIT2:

I actually found the SNCF logo with the correct stencil font on an old photo I took:

[image]

Comment: Probably not a font but rather a stenchil

Comment: @joojaa yes, probably. I've found a close match, and added it as an answer. Not an exact match but it might help some people.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a font that looks close enough. It's not exactly the same, as it's pretty recent (2008):

Ironstrike Extra Bold Italic:

[image: Ironstrike Extra Bold Italic]

It's not an exact match, as it misses some "roundess", the S bar is not slanted enough, the 7 misses the bar, and the 3 have an extra feature, but that's already a good starting point!

Comment: too bad the "S" is not as nice as the Original you are looking for. That is one good-looking S. ;)

Comment: Yes it's so good-looking! I might just have to create my own font ;)